# how to set accelerator (access key) for an imagebutton

Tags: c#, wpf, button, accessibility

Imagebutton is a hybrid consisting of image and text. See here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/knom/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton
- http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties

I use the first method because it is most straightforward for me.

Now, the problem is I would like to have an accelerator for such button which would behave **exactly** like accelerator for a normal button.

I tried to register access key and use textblock for displaying text, but then I am unable to show underscore. When I use label instead of textblock then I get underscore, but label treats it as access key on its own overriding registered access key for button -- so when I press it the label is just focused, but there is no "click" action for button.

**How to have both worlds -- underscore when [alt] is pressed and "click" action for button?**

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the `Target` property for the `Label`.

For example:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image/>
        <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=myButton}">
            _Click Me
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```